# Position textView and control its width and height

Tags: android, textview

How can I customize the TextView and position it there so that it only covers a selected part of the screen as in the link?

[image]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/a879/0r389nv7ynb3yu0zg.jpg))</sub>

http://www.mediafire.com/view/0r389nv7ynb3yu0/Screenshot_2015-04-18-23-58-14+-+Copy+%282%29.png#

The snapshot is drawn using Paint. I have the x, y coordinates as well of the rectangle shown in the link but how can I do this with textView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, this should do it.

Give it a height and width using dp, then use "align" and then margin.

Example:

```
<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

Comment: awesome @Alexander, with just a slight change in margin top value, it worked perfectly. Thanks man.